# .getJSON caching data

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

It is possible to cache .getJSON query with localStorage/sessionStorage or in a cookie for an X hour?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var rateYesterday;
  $.getJSON( "http://api.fixer.io/<?php echo date("Y-m-d", time() - 60 * 60 * 24) ?>",  function(dd) {
    cache: true;
    rateYesterday = dd;
  }); 

  var rateToday;
  $.getJSON( "http://api.fixer.io/latest", function(jd) {
    rateToday = jd;
    cache: true;
    console.log( "success" + rateToday['rates']['HUF'] );
    $('#first').html(rateToday['rates']['HUF']);
    $('#second').html(rateToday['rates']['CZK']);
    if (rateToday['rates']['HUF'] >= rateYesterday['rates']['HUF'] ) {
      $('#firstrate').addClass('goood');
    }
    if (rateToday['rates']['HUF'] < rateYesterday['rates']['HUF'] ) {
      $('#firstrate').addClass('baaad');
    }
    if (rateToday['rates']['CZK'] >= rateYesterday['rates']['CZK'] ) {
      $('#secondrate').addClass('goood');
    }
    if (rateToday['rates']['CZK'] < rateYesterday['rates']['CZK'] ) {
      $('#secondrate').addClass('baaad');
    }    
})
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })

});
</script>
```

I set cache: true in the code, but it is not really caches the data.

Interesting that If I press refresh button for a few times I sometimes get:

```
TypeError: rateYesterday is undefined
if (rateToday['rates']['HUF'] >= rateYesterday['rates']['HUF'] ) {
```

Comment: This would be better done on the server. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324541/caching-json-apache-php-jquery) and its related questions.

Comment: What is the higher level objective... don't make request if data exists in storage and is not expired?

Comment: Also note that the reason you get undefined is second request can easily complete before the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comment pointed out this might be better done on server but for sake of pulling this off and answering question yes you can do this. Here is one way:

```
function HourCache (jsonData) {
    var stringValue;
    if (typeof jsonData === 'string') {
        stringValue = jsonData;
    }
    else {
        stringValue = JSON.stringify(jsonData)
    } 
    sessionStorage.setItem('jsonData', stringValue);
    setTimeout(
        function () {
            sessionStorage.removeItem('jsonData');
        }, 3600000
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I try this and server method too. I am just learning.